# SQl:how to write a query for least times id is presnt in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "UserPlay" which as values like this

```
th_id    route_id
1         1
1         2
1         2
1         3
1         3
```

I just want least time rout_id is used

I have to get output as this

```
th_id    route
1          1
```

Comment: your example is very unclear. what is input, what is expected output? give multiple example queries, please.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the `route_id` with the lowest count:

```
select route_id, count(*)
from UserPlay u
group by route_id
order by count(*) asc
limit 1;
```

You can get the list of `the_id` on it by including `group_concat(the_id)`.

Comment: Actually i want a query for this

Comment: `"with the lowest count"` probably `ORDER BY ASC` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9911b5/3/0

Comment: @lad2025 . . . LOL.  That would seem to be the more correct interpretation.

Comment: Actually i want a query for this  i have selected  a Treasure Hunt for Mysore which is (th_id=1 )and for that treasure hunt there are 3 routes as (1,2,3)   route id 2,3 are used 2 times the least time used is 1 i want that as an input